# Lidgren is not sending/receiving Data messages

Tags: c#, udp, lidgren

I have grabbed the latest edition of Lidgren, from https://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/

I've reviewed many tutorials, but none seem to work.  I presume I must be missing something in my code.

```
using Lidgren.Network;
using System;
namespace LGServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NetPeerConfiguration config = new NetPeerConfiguration("test");
            config.Port = 5432;
            config.LocalAddress = new System.Net.IPAddress(new byte[] { 127, 0, 0, 1 });
            config.MaximumConnections = 1000;
            NetServer server = new NetServer(config);
            server.Start();
            NetIncomingMessage msg = null;
            while (true)
            {
                while ((msg = server.ReadMessage()) != null)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(msg.MessageType.ToString());
                    if (msg.MessageType == NetIncomingMessageType.Data)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(msg.ReadInt16());
                        Console.WriteLine(msg.ReadString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
//// My client code:
using Lidgren.Network;
using System;
namespace LGClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NetPeerConfiguration config = new NetPeerConfiguration("test");
            NetClient client = new NetClient(config);
            client.Start();
            client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 5432);
            NetOutgoingMessage msg = client.CreateMessage();
            msg.Write((Int16)3346);
            msg.Write("Test Message 1 whooahaa");
            client.SendMessage(msg, NetDeliveryMethod.ReliableUnordered);
            client.FlushSendQueue();
        }
    }
}
```

The server gets a status change every time I connect (?status changes from running to running?)
Then I get a debug message with the time it takes between client/server

But I never get the data message.  does this code work on someone elses machine?  is there something obvious I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: I found the problem, but I don't understand why it is a problem.  By simply adding "Thread.Sleep(500);" right after the client connects (before sending the data message) it works fine.  I don't see how the delay helps.  Is it essentially the time it takes for the lidgren server to register the connection to approve messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that between the time connection (a message on its own) and the first data message, the connection had not been fully setup on the server side.  As a hack on my proof, I simply added a short delay (Thread.Sleep(500)).  For a more effective fix, I plan on implementing a response message from the server prior to the client sending more.

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to send a message as soon as you connect you should send your message when you receive a statuschange update from the server that notifies that you've connected as Connect does not block nor prevent subsequent code from executing if you've yet to establish a connection.

Comment: This is a very good way to improve the initial handshake protocol.